# Tkinter Label not showing Int variable

Tags: python, variables, tkinter, label

I'm trying to make a simple RPG where as you collect gold it will be showed in a label, but it doesn't!!
Here is the code:

```
def start():

    Inv=Tk()

    gold = IntVar(value=78)


    EtkI2=Label(Inv, textvariable=gold).pack()
```

I'm new to python and especially tkinter so I need help!!!

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: For lables you need StringVar.

Comment: @Marcin: not true. You can use an IntVar if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing wrong with your code is that you aren't calling the `mainloop` method of the root window. Once you do that, your code works fine.

Here's a slightly modified version that updates the value after 5 seconds:

```
from Tkinter import *

def start():
    Inv = Tk()
    Inv.geometry("200x200")

    gold = IntVar(value=78)
    EtkI2=Label(Inv, textvariable=gold).pack()

    # chanage the gold value after 5 seconds
    Inv.after(5000, gold.set, 100)

    # start the event loop
    Inv.mainloop()


start()
```

There are some other things that could be improved with your code. For exaple, `EtkI2` will be set to `None` since that is what `pack()` returns. It's best to separate widget creation from widget layout. Also, it's better to *not* do a global import (`from Tkinter import *`). I recommend `import Tkinter as tk ... tk.Label(...)`.

I explain more about that along with using an object-oriented approach here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17470842

Comment: Thanks a lot!! But I have another question: How can I do to modify that variable gold ? gold.set(13) Is ok ?

Comment: @gigixtocco: yes, `gold.set(...)` is the way to change it.